# Greensfunction symmetric with respect to arguments

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, greens-function

Let $\widehat{\cal O}$ be an $n$-dimensional differential operator i.e. for $n=1$ it leads to an ordinary differential equation and for $n>1$ to a partial differential equation. The Greensfunction $G$ obeys
$$
\widehat{\cal O} \, G\left(\vec{x},\vec{x}'\right) = \delta\left(\vec{x}-\vec{x}'\right)
$$
where the operator acts on $\vec{x}$.
I'm wondering if $G$ in general is symmetric with respect to its arguments.
If the Operator is translational invariant, then the Greensfunction is of the form $G\left(\vec{x}-\vec{x}'\right)$. If it is not I do not see why it should be symmetric.
If $\Psi\left(\vec{x}\right)$ is a solution of the inhomogenous equation
$$
\widehat{\cal O} \, \Psi\left(\vec{x}\right) = \omega\left(\vec{x}\right)
$$
then it seems to be sufficient, that $G$ solves the first equation only with respect to $\vec{x}$, because
$$
\Psi\left(\vec{x}\right) = \int_V G\left(\vec{x},\vec{x}'\right) \omega\left(\vec{x}'\right) \, {\rm d}V'
$$
and no solution with respect to $\vec{x}'$ is required.
Are there other criteria? For the laplacian the Greensfunction $G=-\frac{1}{4\pi\left|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'\right|}$ indeed seems to be symmetric, but the laplacian in cartesian coordinates is translationally invariant.

Or must this eigendecomposition
$$
G\left(\vec{x},\vec{x}'\right) = \sum_n \frac{\psi_n\left(\vec{x}\right)\psi_n\left(\vec{x}'\right)}{\lambda_n}
$$
always hold, where $\psi_n$ is normalized and solves
$$
\widehat{\cal O} \, \psi_n = \lambda_n \psi_n \, .
$$
Are there Greensfunction which are not representable like this? Why should any Greensfunction be precisely of this form?